# PipWriter.Write does not write into stream. Return value was 0

Tags: go

Use case (trimmed and converted for public share)

We are trying to run a long-running process and want to stream the output to the caller function.

```
 func (c *Command) GetResultStream(config *Config, outputWriter *io.PipeWriter, errorWriter *io.PipeWriter) (*Result, bool) {
    log.Printf("Executing the command %q with config %q", c.String(), config.String())
    cmd := exec.Command(c.Command, c.Arguments...)

    if config.RedirectErrorStream {
        return &Result{
            ExitCode: ExitCodeInvalidInputConfiguration,
            Output:   "",
            Errors:   []string{"Cannot enable RedirectErrorStream configuration for Streaming output"},
        }, false
    }

    outputReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    defer common.CloseQuitely(outputReader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error occurred while getting the output stream for the command %q. Error is %v", c.String(), err)
        return &Result{
            ExitCode: ExitCodeUnableToGetStdOutStream,
            Output:   "",
            Errors:   []string{err.Error()},
        }, false
    }
    errorReader, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    defer common.CloseQuitely(errorReader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error occurred while getting the error stream for the command %q. Error is %v", c.String(), err)
        return &Result{
            ExitCode: ExitCodeUnableToGetStdErrStream,
            Output:   "",
            Errors:   []string{err.Error()},
        }, false
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error occurred while starting the cmmand %q. Error is %v", c.String(), err)
        return &Result{
            ExitCode: ExitCodeFailedToStartCommand,
            Output:   "",
            Errors:   []string{err.Error()},
        }, false
    }

    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer waitGroup.Done()
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(outputReader)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()
            _, err := outputWriter.Write([]byte(line))
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error occurred while writing to output writer. Error is %v", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer waitGroup.Done()
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(errorReader)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()
            _, err := errorWriter.Write([]byte(line))
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error occurred while writing to error writer. Error is %v", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error occurred while waiting for the command %q to finish. Error is %v ", c.String(), err)
        exitCode := ExitCodeSuccess
        if exitError, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
            exitCode = exitError.ExitCode()
        }
        return &Result{
            ExitCode: exitCode,
            Output:   "",
            Errors:   []string{err.Error()},
        }, false
    }

    waitGroup.Wait()

    return &Result{
        ExitCode: 0,
        Output:   "",
        Errors:   nil,
    }, true

}
```

Caller code

```
cmd := command.NewCommand("tail", "-f", "/private/tmp/test.txt")

outputReader, outputWriter := io.Pipe()

errorReader, errorWriter := io.Pipe()
defer common.CloseQuitely(errorReader)
defer common.CloseQuitely(errorWriter)

var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
waitGroup.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer waitGroup.Done()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(outputReader)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Print(line)
    }
}()

res, ok := cmd.GetResultStream(command.DefaultConfig, outputWriter, errorWriter)

if !ok {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to run the command %q. Error is %v", cmd.String(), res.Errors)
    return
}

waitGroup.Wait()
```

We are getting data into go routine in the GetResultStream method and we are calling outputWriter.Write method  but it is not getting written and thus not returned to the caller. On debugging Write method returns 0 bytes wrote.

Comment: have you tried to create a minimal reproducable example? Alot of time the issue becomes apparent when doing this and you can answer your own question. If not, you can post the example here.

Comment: Simplify the code by using `outputWriter` and `errorWriter` directly: `cmd.Stdout = outputWriter; cmd.Stderr = errorWriter`.  Because the caller code does not read from `errorReader`,  `GetResultStream` will block forever if the command writes any data to stderr.

Comment: You are using line scanners for all reading, stripping out the newlines, so there are no lines for your final scanner to read.

Comment: to re phrase JimB's comment: `outputWriter.Write([]byte(line+"\n"))`. Why do you do such complicated implementation ? Follow on Zombo 's advices.

Comment: Thanks all.  The issue was with reading from the main function. I agree, I was making it complicated.  Followed Zombo's advice and the complexity of the GetResultStream were reduced significantly.